# Revoke CONNECT permission to new DB by default

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

this is happening on newly created Postgres 13 instance on GCP's Cloud SQL.

I would like to disallow users to CONNECT to newly created databases. So I am modifying template database:

`REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE template1 FROM public;`

Then, I create new Database:

`CREATE DATABASE mydb TEMPLATE template1;`

Then I am checking CONNECT permissions for existing user:

```
SELECT datname
FROM pg_database
WHERE has_database_privilege('someuser', datname, 'CONNECT')

    datname
---------------
 cloudsqladmin
 postgres
 template0
 mydb
```

So as you can see `someuser` has `CONNECT` permission to `mydb`.

Why is this happening? How can I prevent users to connect to newly created databases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permissions on a database are *not* copied from the template database during `CREATE DATABASE`. Rather, all new databases have the same default permissions: `CONNECT` and `TEMP` for `PUBLIC`, and all permissions for the owner.

There is no way to change that default, short of modifying the PostgreSQL code.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I suspected it worked that way.